# GCMRegistrar jar causing error in eclipse , source not found. Stalls debugging

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to register an Android app with google GCM and it seems to be causing an error in eclipse.  Any Help?

blows up as soon as I try to check if its registered. Its compiles fine and I have added the  `import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;`  I think this is more about me not understanding java and eclipse, than GCM, but who knows

I've added step filters to ignore `com.google.android.gcm.*`

and I've made sure to include the gdm.jar library in my local libs folder with my project and the build path.

If i step through the code, it stops when I try to step over the first line where `GCMRegistrar` is referenced and says and says 'source not found'. If I put no breakpoints, it still stops when it hits `GCMRegistrar` and says 'source not found'.

```
private void checkRegistration(){
    try{
            if (!GCMRegistrar.isRegistered(getApplicationContext())) {
                 // Automatically registers application on startup.
                GCMRegistrar.register(getApplicationContext(), Utilities.GCM_SENDER_ID);
            } else {
                final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(getApplicationContext());
                if(regId.equals("")){
                    GCMRegistrar.register(getApplicationContext(), Utilities.GCM_SENDER_ID);
                }else{
                // Device is already registered on GCM

                    if(regId == Utilities.getGcmRegKey(this)){

                    }else{
                        pwClient.updateGCMRef("add", regId, Utilities.getApiKey(this), Utilities.getDeviceId(this));
                        Utilities.setGcmRegKey(this, regId);
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            Log.e("PW", "register error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not an exception, its as if eclipse is trying to step through code i dont have the source for. It stalls and says `source not found`

Comment: When you open libs folder inside eclipse, does the gcm.jar has a little thingy on the icon to state that it's in your build path?

Comment: `little thingy`? is that a technical term?  it looks like [this](http://imgur.com/FJORR)

Comment: What happens if you run it instead of debug it? Can you see anything in logcat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to stop working on my GCM project, but I did at least manage to get the source for the GCM client side stuff, so it might help you debug a bit. Starting with the R17 SDK tools Google have made attaching source and javadocs a right pain, but it can be done.

In the same 'dist' directory where you found the gcm.jar is another jar gcm-src.jar - that's the source. So in your libs directory make a new file called gcm.jar.properties.

It should contain one line like

```
src=C:\\dev\\tools\\android-sdk-windows4.1\\extras\\google\\gcm\\gcm-client\\dist\\gcm-src.jar
```

(Edit this to refer to your SDK installation, changing the \\s  to /s if you are on Linux)

Now close your project and reopen it, otherwise it won't work, heaven knows why!

You should now have 'hover over' javadoc type popups and be able to step into the GCMRegistrar static methods. As to why your code blows up, maybe this will get you closer.

Incidentally the sample code I based my project on had these two lines at the start of the registration

```
// Check that the device supports GCM (should be in a try / catch)
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
// Check the manifest to be sure this app has all the required permissions.
GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
```

They might shed some light on things

Comment: adding the properties file did the trick. there was no underlying error in gcm. so why would i need the source to step OVER this stuff?

Comment: I'm not sure why you can't step over without the source. Perhaps it's just another Eclipse Android plugin inconsistency?

Answer (score 0):

According to [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html), GCM requires Android **2.2** or later, first check if your manifest sdk versions are correct

Second, right click on your project and select **Properties** => **Java Build Path** => **Libraries** tab and ensure gcm.jar exist in the list